# Why do i get an error for calculating barycentric weights in this function?

Tags: matlab, octave, interpolation

I implemented the following in Octave/Matlab for calculating the barycentric weights:

```
function omega = bary_gewichte(m)
omega = nan(size(m+1));
for k = 0:m+1
  omega(k) = ((-1).^k) .* (factorial(m))./(factorial(k) .* factorial(m-i)); 
endfor
endfunction
```

But I get the error:

```
error: factorial: all N must be real non-negative integers
```

But I guess all results are not negative for positive m. How can I get this function working?

Comment: Your loop index is `k` but you called `factorial(m-i)`.

Comment: but now i get: error: omega(0): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^63)-1 or logicals

Comment: okay, i need an index shift. 0:m+1 to 1:m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works:

```
function omega = bary_gewichte(m)
  omega = nan(size(m+1));
  for k = 0:m
    omega(k+1) = ((-1).^k) .* (factorial(m))./(factorial(k) .* factorial(m-k)); 
  endfor
endfunction
```

Notice that you wrote `for k=0:m+1 ...`. In the last iteration we get the state `m-k=-1`, but `factorial(-1)` is undefined. Also in Matlab, indexing starts with 1.
I dont know your task, so I dont know if that solves your problem.